# Visualizing multiple dummy variables over time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with dummy variables for daily weather types observations.

```
         date  high_wind  thunder  snow  smoke
0  2050-10-23        1.0      NaN   NaN    NaN
1  2050-10-24        1.0      1.0   NaN    NaN
2  2050-10-25        NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
3  2050-10-26        NaN      NaN   NaN    1.0
4  2050-10-27        NaN      NaN   NaN    1.0
5  2050-10-28        NaN      NaN   NaN    1.0
6  2050-10-29        1.0      NaN   NaN    NaN
7  2050-10-30        NaN      1.0   NaN    NaN
8  2050-10-31        NaN      1.0   NaN    NaN
9  2050-11-01        1.0      1.0   NaN    NaN
10 2050-11-02        1.0      1.0   NaN    NaN
11 2050-11-03        1.0      1.0   NaN    NaN
12 2050-11-04        1.0      NaN   NaN    NaN
13 2050-11-05        1.0      NaN   NaN    NaN
14 2050-11-06        NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
15 2050-11-07        NaN      1.0   NaN    NaN
16 2050-11-08        NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
17 2050-11-09        NaN      NaN   1.0    NaN
18 2050-11-10        NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
19 2050-11-11        NaN      NaN   1.0    NaN
20 2050-11-12        NaN      NaN   1.0    NaN
21 2050-11-13        NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
```

For those of you playing along at home, copy the above and then:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()    
df.date = df.date.apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

I want to visualize this dataframe with the date on the x axis and each weather type category on the y axis. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labels = df.columns.tolist()

#unsatisfying loop to give categories some y separation
for i,col in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax.scatter(x=df[col].index, y=(df[col]+i)) #add a little to each
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xlim(df.index.min(), df.index.max())
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Which gives me this:

[image: lousy category plot]

## Questions:

1. How do I get the y labels aligned properly?
2. Is there a better way to structure the data to make plotting easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This aligns you y labels:

```
ax.set_yticks(range(1, len(df.columns) + 1))
```

[image]